# Why am I getting zero when I multiply doubles?

Tags: c#

I made this line of code while debugging:
`double hola = (1 / 2) * (double)x.height;`
height is a double. Hola is just a temporary name.

When I debug, I see that x.height = 1, and hola = 0.

What did I do wrong? I'm pretty sure I made some really simple mistake..

Also when I remove the double casting that I do to x.height I still get hola = 0.

Comment: I really wish the compiler warned about this. People make this mistake all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1 / 2` is zero, remainder one. Zero times anything is zero.

Did you mean to write `1.0 / 2.0`?

Answer (score 4):

`1` and `2` are both `int`, so the result of `1/2` will be cast (truncated) to an int. `0.5` -> `0`.

You need to make sure either of the operands supports decimal points:

```
double hola = (1.0 / 2) * (double)x.height;
```

Or:

```
double hola = ((double)1 / 2) * (double)x.height;
```

Comment: This is not correct. The result will be 0. It will neither be cast nor truncated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The result of `1/2` is truncated to `0`.

Comment: No, it's not. The result of `1/2` is zero. That's how integer division works. Nothing is truncated. You can't represent `0.5` as an integer, even to truncate it to zero, and no other representation is used here.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz We're really splitting hairs then, as the *mathematical* result of 1/2 is 0.5, the fact that the `DIV` operator in the CIL only pushes the quotient is really an implementation detail. Mathematically, it is truncated (pushing only the quotient instead of the full result *is* a truncation).

Comment: When you say "the mathematical result of 1/2", by "/" you mean a completely different operation than the one used here, which is integer division. Sure, you could imagine that the result of 1.0/2.0 is being truncated as another way to get the same result, but that's just not what's happening. The only operation involved here is integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing two integers will performs an integer division, which gives the result also in the same type(fractional part is truncated).Where a non-integer division(here double) on int arguments by explicitly casting at least one of the arguments to a double. So your code will be :

```
 double hola = (1 / (double)2) * (double)x.height;
```

OR

```
double hola = ((double)1 / 2) * (double)x.height;
```